# WinRT Xaml ListView - Touch doesn't scroll well

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I have a horizontal list view that scrolls offscreen to the right, such as this:

[image]

The problem is, when using touch you can't swipe to scroll the ListView by default, it seems to just grab the ListView item and pull it horizontally a little bit.  The only way I can get it to scroll is to click the 5-10 pixels in between each ListViewItem, which is horrible.

Is there a setting to modify this behavior?

My Xaml is basically this:

```
            <ListView 
                x:Name="listView" Grid.Column="1" IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Assignments}" SelectionMode="None" ItemClick="OnItemClick">
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                       <!--cool template to make UI in screenshot-->
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Should I ask Jerry?

[image: JERRY!!!!]

Comment: What does your itemclick event do?

Comment: It navigates to another page, which I still need.  I also need to be able to scroll though.  I also tried turning off `IsItemClickEnabled`, but same result (except my `ItemClick` doesn't fire).

Comment: If you don't want selection then why not use an itemscontrol in a scrollview instead of the listview?

Comment: We want to keep the bounce effect when you click a ListViewItem, but you don't "select" one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, it was due to having a parent `ScrollViewer` outside of the `ListView`, I have a large "panorama" with 4 or 5 controls within it, including the `ListView`.

I able to fix it by setting this on the `ListView`:

`ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"`

Comment: I don't understand `ScrollViewer`, the scrolling doesn't seem to work with `ScrollViewer` contradiction to the **Name**

Comment: You have to set `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollbarVisibility` and such before it will work.