# Horizontal ListView items do not scroll when swiped in WinRT app?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a C# WinRT/8.1 app that uses a ListView with a child stack panel to show items in a horizontal row.  That works fine, except I am having the same problem discussed in this SO post:

[WinRT Xaml ListView - Touch doesn't scroll well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128001/winrt-xaml-listview-touch-doesnt-scroll-well)

Except worse.  My items don't scroll even when the fingertip is pressed on the margin between items.  Unfortunately I don't have a parent Panorama control or ScrollView control to blame.  How can I fix this?

NOTE: I switched to a ListView from a GridView because of SO posts I read that indicated GridView's with horizontal items are problematic, which was the case for me.

Here is the XAML for the page:

```
<Page
    <!-- headers snipped for brevity -->
    <Page.Resources>
        <Converters:DebugBindingConverter x:Key="DebugBindingConverter"/>
        <Converters:VideomarkLocationToString x:Key="VideomarkLocationToString"/>
        <common:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="HorzVideomarksItemTemplate1">
            <Grid d:DesignWidth="977" d:DesignHeight="746" Height="121" Width="252">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="52*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="23*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtLocation" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding OffsetSecs, Converter={StaticResource VideomarkLocationToString}}" Grid.Row="2" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtNote" Text="{Binding Text}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                <Image x:Name="imgThumbnail" Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding ThumbnailAsync}"/>
                <!-- <TextBlock x:Name="txtTest2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="81,93,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                    Text="{Binding Videomarks, Converter={StaticResource DebugBindingConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="87" Width="150" FontSize="12"/> -->
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="gridPage" 
        Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="25" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="897*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="469*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="347*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="231*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Back button and page title -->
        <Grid x:Name="gridTopRow" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="backButton" Margin="39,59,39,0" Command="{Binding NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}"
                Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                AutomationProperties.Name="Back"
                AutomationProperties.AutomationId="BackButton"
                AutomationProperties.ItemType="Navigation Button"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="{StaticResource AppName}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,894,40" Tapped="pageTitle_Tapped"/>
            <Button x:Name="exitButton"
                Click="exitButton_Click"
                Style="{StaticResource ClosePaneAppBarButtonStyle}" Margin="1065,27,0,9" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" Visibility="{Binding Main.IsDebuggerAttached, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <Button x:Name="btnTest" Content="test" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="883,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="36" Click="btnTest_Click" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        </Grid>
        <WebView x:Name="webViewVideoPlayer" Grid.Row="1" ScriptNotify="ScriptNotifyPlayLocation" Margin="25" />
        <Button x:Name="btnVideomark" Content="Bookmark" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="578,53,0,0" Height="54" FontSize="26.667" Click="btnVideomark_Click" Width="181"/>
        <ListView 
                x:Name="listviewVideomarks" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="20"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Videomarks.VideomarksCollection, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HorzVideomarksItemTemplate1}" SelectionMode="None" 
                    >
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="stackVideomarksHorz" Orientation="Horizontal">

                    </StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>

        <Border x:Name="borderAddVideomark" BorderThickness="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="369,53,319,112" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="#FF144989" CornerRadius="25" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" Loaded="border_Loaded">
            <Grid x:Name="gridAddVideomark" IsHitTestVisible="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Opacity="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="187*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="188*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="189*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="137*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="62*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock x:Name="lblVideomarkLocation" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" Margin="40,10,10,10" FontSize="18.667"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtVideomarkNote" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10,10,10,2"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnOk" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="92,10,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="192" Foreground="White" FontSize="21.333" Height="45" Click="btnOk_Click"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="88,10,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="192" Foreground="White" FontSize="21.333" Height="45" Grid.Column="1" Click="btnCancel_Click"/>
                <Rectangle x:Name="rectVideomarkThumbnail" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stroke="Black" Margin="10"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Why is "IsHitTestVisible" set to false on quite a few things? Also, if you don't need vertical scrolling, disable it and explicitly enable horizontal scrolling. Use `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` and `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode` (and their horizontal counterparts).

Comment: @NateDiamond I'm using Visual States.  I cut that out of the xaml block because none of the states are active at the point of my testing so they shouldn't be active.  With them the XAML block would have been a lot longer and harder to sift through.

Comment: You may want to try playing with `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollChaining`.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure which directions you are trying to scroll, but I think your problem will be fixed if you disable the `StackPanel` scroll and enable scrolling in both directions on the `ListView`.

```
<ListView 
    x:Name="listviewVideomarks" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="20"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Videomarks.VideomarksCollection, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HorzVideomarksItemTemplate1}" SelectionMode="None" 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
    >
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel x:Name="stackVideomarksHorz" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" 
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">

            </StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```